# Why is the square of the first moment is always less than the second moment?

Tags: statistics, expected-value

Recently in a lecture I was told that for any random variable X, $[E(X)]^2 < E(X^2)$. However, I'm not sure where this property comes from. Could anyone provide hints/prove why this property holds true? Thank you!

Comment: When we calculate $E(X)$ , we might be adding Positive & Negative Quantities , which will "Partially" Cancel each other & we might end up with a Quantity somewhat "less" & we can Square this "smaller" Quantity to get $E(X)^2$ ; When we calculate $E(X^2)$ , all Quantities become Positive only & nothing will Cancel & it will be somewhat "more" & we end up with a "larger" Quantity. User @Bob has already given Example to high-light that it is not "$\lt$" but "$\leq$" but had no Proof : My Comment is a Simple Proof

Comment: I would like to give my intuition which is lack of rigorousness, it might be quite similar to the case that we understand why $|x + y|  \leq |x| + |y|$. The triangular inequality holds since there might be an "inner loss" while summing $x$ and $y$ up just before taking the absolute value, since $x$ and $y$ can have opposite signs. Similarly, if you take the expectation firstly on R.V. $X$, there might also be a "loss" since $X$ may take negative values. However, if you square the R.V. $X$ firstly, $X^2$ would always be non-negative and hence avoid the "loss" that caused by averaging.

Answer (score 1):

The assertion is that $[E(X)]^2\le E(X^2)$. Here is an elementary proof: Use the fact that $E(X^2)-[E(X)]^2$ [can be written](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/755326/215011)
$$E(X^2)-[E(X)]^2=E[(X-E(X))^2].\tag1$$
But the random variable $(X-E(X))^2$ is non-negative, so its expectation is non-negative. Therefore $E(X^2)-[E(X)]^2\ge0$.

In fact the RHS of (1) is definition of the variance of $X$.

Answer (score 0):

I claim that your statement is not true. That is,
$$ [E(X)]^2 < E(X^2)$$
is not true. Please consider the random variable $X$ that can take
only one value, $0$. In this case, we have $E(X) = 0$ and $E(X^2) = 0$. I am thinking you were told for any random variable $X$, $[E(X)]^2 \leq E(X^2)$. I believe, but I am not entirely sure that is true. At the moment, I do not know how to prove it however.

Comment: It follows by applying Cauchy-Schwarz ($\|fg\|_{L^1}\leq \|f\|_{L^2}\cdot \|g\|_{L^2}$, which can be viewed as the extremely special case of Holder's inequality with exponents $p=q=2$) to $X=X\cdot 1$, and using the fact that we're working with probablity measures, so $\|1\|_{L^2}=1$. Or, you can view this as an application of Jensen's inequality ($f(t)=t^2$ is a convex function on $[0,\infty)$).